# ImageCopyMerge appearing not to merge

Tags: php, html, image

ImageCopyMerge only appears to only process the bottom image?

As a trial I am trying to overlay and offset a white and blue image

```
$dest = '../images/pictures/white.gif';
$src = '../images/pictures/blue.gif';
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 12, 65, 0, 0, 175, 260, 50);
imagegif($dest);
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

and then later in the HTML display the output

```
<img src="<?php echo($dest); ?>" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do process your images first need to load the images into RAM using the `imagecreatefrom*` functions.

```
$dest = imagecreatefromgif(''../images/pictures/white.gif');
$src = imagecreatefromgif('../images/pictures/blue.gif');
```

The following won't work either.

```
<img src="<?php echo($dest); ?>" />
```

You either need to link to the php script which calls the [`imagegif()`](http://php.net/imagegif) function

```
<img src="your/script.php" />
```

or you need to convert the imagedata into an [data URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (but i wouldn't recomend that if the image is large).

```
ob_start();
imagegif($dest);
$imagedata = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,"' . base64($imagedata) . '" />';
```

Comment: I'm taking all this on board. But can I change the line to imagegif($dest, 'output.gif'); and then display output.gif later on normally, <img src="output.gif" />.

Comment: @EdwardHasted You could do that. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Yes, it was the imagecreatefromgif that I missed out. Very many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

do like this, you are destroying the image and using after that because of that it was not coming.

```
<?php
$dest = '../images/pictures/white.gif';
$src = '../images/pictures/blue.gif';
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 12, 65, 0, 0, 175, 260, 50);
imagegif($dest);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $dest; ?>" />   // your html code
<?php
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Comment: I doctored the code before I posted it but you're absolutley right and good idea. I will use it :-)